# Do Jews accept the Bible as the inspired word of God?

Tags: tanach

According to the New Testament, the Bible is the inspired Word of God Himself. 
2 Timothy 3:16.

> All Scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness

Which, if any, part of the Bible is accepted by Jews? Would it be the books of Moses?

The Bible prophesies concerning Israel are many and many have come to pass, but there are still others to happen. Indeed the Bible is full of prophesies concerning Jerusalem and Israel and I wondered what is accepted as truth in Jewish belief?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Jewish Bible does not contain the twenty-seven books of what are called the New Testament in the Christian Bible nor the additional books accepted as inspired by Roman Catholics and Greek Orthodox Christians in what is called the Old Testament but which are not found in the Jewish Bible, namely, *Tobit*, *Judith*, *The 1st Book of Maccabees*, *The 2nd Book of Maccabees*, *The Book of Wisdom*, *Ecclesiasticus/Ben Sira*, and *Baruch*.   The Jewish Bible is commonly called the Tanakh, an acronym for Torah, Neviim, Ketuvim--the three divisions of the text. These divisions are different from those in Christian Bibles. Most importantly, the interpretation of the material in common with Christians differs. For example, *Isaiah* 7:14 is not considered a text predicting a supernatural virginal conception for the Messiah, nor *Psalm* 45:7a a text predicitng that he would be God, as it is read in *Letter to the Hebrews* 1:8-9 
(And about the Son [Jesus] he [God] says, 'Your throne, O God, is for ever and ever . . . .')

Comment: My only comment is that from the reply, I can see why Jews don't believe in Jesus, because they don't believe the Bible is the inspired word of God? Would this be a correct assumption?

Comment: @Peergint Jews believe that the Hebrew Bible is the inspired word of God. However they don't accept the Greek additions as being part of the Bible.

Comment: @Peergint No, Jews do not accept Jesus because according to our reading and understanding of the Inspired Word of G-d (the Hebrew Bible), he doesn't fit the bill of the Messiah.

Comment: Would I be right in saying it's all about genealogy? Book of Matthew saying He came from the line of Joseph, although He is not Joseph's Son by birth, and from Luke because He is from Mary's line, even though this line goes back to David but not through Solomon?

Comment: Peergint No. You are not correct in saying that the problem with Jesus is all about genealogy. The genealogy problem is just one of several, he being disqualified on that point by both divergent genealogies in Matthew and Luke, neither of which descriibe him as a naturally born son of Joseph. See the essay 'Why don't Jews believe in Jesus' @SimpleToRemember.com.

Comment: It's all about the interpretation of the material in common that is crucial.  Jews read the Hebrew one way, Christians another.

Comment: @PeergintRemember: the Hebrew Bible was written in Hebrew by Hebrews for Hebrews. Not one book in the Tanakh was written by a Gentile in a Gentile language.

Comment: Hello Clifford. I will most certainly take a look at @simpletoremember. Thank you.